# How to integrate IgniteUI igGrid (Infragistics) with AngularJS and export to Excel

Tags: angularjs, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am new to AngularJS and IgniteUI. So far, I could not find any good example to integrate infragistics IgniteUI with AngularJS. The samples I have found does not work.

Based on the sample I have integrated the following files

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>    

<script src="~/Scripts/Infragistics/js/infragistics.core.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/Infragistics/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>    

<script src="~/Scripts/Infragistics/js/extensions/igniteui-angular.js"></script>

<script src="~/App/igniteUIApp.js"></script>

<div ng-app="igniteUIApp" ng-controller="SampleController">

    <ig-grid id="grid1" 
             data-source="employees" 
             primary-key="EmployeeID" 
             auto-generate-columns="true">
    </ig-grid>
</div>
```

I would like to see the following

Step 1
 How to populate the igGrid with $scope.datasource?

Step 2
 How to export the igGrid data to Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I've prepared a fiddle demonstrating this - http://jsfiddle.net/dkamburov/g34wy1mc/2/

Assigning some data into scope property is enough to populate the grid data - `$scope.data = angular.copy(northwindProducts.results);`

Make sure you have all the needed references for the excel exporter and then all you need is `$.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid($("#grid1"));`

Comment: Hi, I do not see any data in the grid at all. I assume the code supposed to populate the grid and by clicking the EXPORT button, it is supposed to create an Excel file. Currently, it does not do anything.  Could you please check what's wrong with the code?